# Qt visual issue - Description on mouse over

Tags: c++, qt

I want to realize the same behavior shown in the picture at following [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSubn.png). 
When the cursor is over a push button for few seconds, it can be see a little description.
How can i realize it in Qt4? 
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QPushButton` has `void setToolTip(const QString &)` method, that does exactly that. If you are not satisfied with it's effects, you can draw your own tooltip widget ( QWidget with Qt::Tooltip flag) and subclass QPushbutton by re-implementing `onMouseEnter` event. Hope that helps.